# Retrieve value from a Json Array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm having difficulty in retrieving values from a Json array. I have a Json dataset that has been created using json_encode. This is how it appears after using json_decode and displaying  using print_r:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [postID] => 1961 [postTitle] => Kiss My Fairy [previewThumb] => 2011/09/Kiss-My-Fairy-Ibiza-essentialibiza-2011_feature.jpg [blogContent] => Ibiza has always had a flair for the extravagant, inhibitions are checked in at the airport when the floods of tourists arrive and the locals have embraced a freedom of partying that has turned the quiet Mediterranean island into the Mecca... ) ) a_post_data_array = 1
```

The code that achieves this is as follows:

```
$post_data_URL = "http://myurl.com/news/scrape/facebook-like-chart-ID.php?post_name=kiss-my-fairy";

$post_data_response = file_get_contents($post_data_URL);  

$a_post_data_array=json_decode($post_data_response);
```

I now simply need to retrieve some of the values from this array to use as variables. The array will only ever have 1 set of values. I'm using the following code but it isn't working.

```
echo "**** -- " . $a_post_data_array[post_title] . "<br>";
```

Can anyone please help? I'm sorry this is so basic. I've been searching online but can't find any examples of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your code:

- First you should instruct [`json_decode`](http://php.net/json_decode) to give you a pure array with `$data = json_decode($response, TRUE);`
- Then the result array is a list, and you have to access the first element as `$data[0]`
- The entry you want to access has the key `postTitle`, not `post_title` as your example code showed. (And unless that's a predefined constant won't work.)
- And you need to put those array keys in quotes, like `print $data[0]["postTitle"];`

Turn up your [`error_reporting`](http://php.net/error_reporting) level for some development help.

Comment: Thank you so much Mario. Will take your advice :)

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "** -- " . $a_post_data_array[0]['post_title'];
```

Answer (score 0):

try this PHP code:

```
//$post_data_response = file_get_contents("https://raw.github.com/gist/1245028/80e690bcbe6f1c5b46676547fbd396ebba97339b/Person_John.json");
//$PersonObject = json_decode($post_data_response);

// Get Person Object from JSON Source
$PersonObject = json_decode('{"ID":"39CA2939-38C0-4C4E-AE6C-CFA5172B8CEB","lastname":"Doe","firstname":"John","age":25,"hobbies":["reading","cinema",{"sports":["volley-ball","snowboard"]}],"address":{}}');

// Get data from Object
echo "Person ID => $PersonObject->ID<br>";
echo "Person Name => $PersonObject->firstname<br>";
echo "Person Lastname => $PersonObject->lastname<br>";  
echo "Person Age => $PersonObject->age<br>";
echo "Person Hobbies => " . $PersonObject->hobbies[0] . "<br>";
```